# jQuery: Repeating Records using for loop array.length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I think I am getting a logic problem using jQuery to fetch record from a service API with AJAX and using following piece of code.

There is no error but this code is repeating records in HTML table (Drafts) -
 like twice.

```
success: function (data) {
  if (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var textDraft = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.TableDrafts.length; i++) {
      textDraft += "<tr><td>" + data.TableDrafts[i].nMBM + "</td><td>" + data.TableDrafts[i].nMTM + "</td><td>" + data.TableDrafts[i].sType + "</td></tr>";
      $("#Drafts").append(textDraft);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `$("#Drafts").append(textDraft);` after the loop

Comment: oh yeah :D thanks man @Satpal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```
success: function (data) {
  if (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var textDraft = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.TableDrafts.length; i++) {
      $("#Drafts").append(`<tr>
        <td>${data.TableDrafts[i].nMBM}</td>
       <td>${data.TableDrafts[i].nMTM}</td>
       <td>${data.TableDrafts[i].sType}</td>
      </tr>`);
     }
  }
}
```

Mistake was, you are adding the new `tr` in the variable as well as appending the variable content.

Or else you can do

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var textDraft = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.TableDrafts.length; i++) {
      textDraft = "<tr><td>" + data.TableDrafts[i].nMBM + "</td><td>" + data.TableDrafts[i].nMTM + "</td><td>" + data.TableDrafts[i].sType + "</td></tr>";
      $("#Drafts").append(textDraft);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.